# Cache WP remote_get HTTP Response using Transients

Tags: plugins, wp-api, http-api

Using wp_remote_get keeps pinging the API on every page load. Which increase the server resource.

Is it possible to cache the response of the API store it using Transients and use it for next 5 minutes instead of keep pinging everytime?

And After 5 Minutes it should send request again and rewrite the stored value.

Here is my code for API Request. How to do this? I'm new to this. Help me please

```
function display_api_response() {
    $api_url = "https://randletter2020.herokuapp.com";
$response = wp_remote_get($api_url);
   if ( 200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response) ) {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

        if ( 'a' === $body ) {
          echo 'A wins';
        }else {
          // Do something else.
        }
   }
}
add_action( 'init', 'display_api_response' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function display_api_response() {
    $body = get_transient( 'my_remote_response_value' );
    
    if ( false === $body ) {
        $api_url = "https://randletter2020.herokuapp.com";
        $response = wp_remote_get($api_url);
    
        if (200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response)) {
            return;
        }
    
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        set_transient( 'my_remote_response_value', $body, 5*MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    if ('a' === $body) {
        echo 'A wins';
    } else {
        // Do something else.
    }
}
add_action('init', 'display_api_response');
```

At first, the transient doesn't exist, so we send a request and save the `$body` as a transient value. Next time, if the transient exists, we skip sending request.

Check the [Transient Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Hector This is Awesome